# Location Bar Doesn't Show Redirected URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

This is my **httpd.conf** file for my `http://old.example.com` :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^login$  http://another.example.com/login   [L]
```

The problem is that although I *can* redirect to `http://another.example.com/login`, but the location bar is still showing `http://old.example.com/login`.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you’re using mod_rewrite in the [server or virtual host configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Context), you always need to specify the full URL path in your patterns:

```
RewriteRule ^/login$ http://another.example.com/login [L,R]
```

Only when used in the per-directory context like in a .htaccess file you just need to specify the relative URL path without the contextual path prefix.

And also try an explicit redirect by setting the [*R* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags):

```
RewriteRule ^/login$ http://another.example.com/login [L,R]
```

With that you can also specify a status code:

```
RewriteRule ^/login$ http://another.example.com/login [L,R=301]
```